# passing parameters to pig within a string using shell expansion

Tags: bash, shell, apache-pig

In PIG, how to pass this in shell

```
{20160218,20160219,20160220,20160221,20160222,20160223,20160224}
```

by shell code like:

```
pig -f cart_abandonment.pig -param input='{20160218..20160224}'
```

using the expansion function?
The above is not working because the single quotes omit the expansion.

Without the single quotes, seems only 20160218 is getting passed.
The PIG script is as:

```
list = load '/inserteddate={$input}' 
    USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as cartjson:map[];
```

Comment: Btw, you should add your specific shell as a tag - I assume you're using [tag:bash]. The [tag:shell] tag is customarily used for questions about POSIX-compliant features, whereas the brace-expansion feature you're using requires `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`.

Comment: Thanks, but the load comment still not working. I added the bash tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a double-quoted command substitution (`$(...)`):

```
pig -f cart_abandonment.pig -param input="$(echo {20160218..20160224} | tr ' ' ',')"
```

- As you've discovered, a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) only works when used *unquoted*.
- However, in order to pass *all* numbers generated by it as part of option-argument `input=`, the number list must be *double-quoted*.
- This is achieved by using a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`) to generate the list of numbers (and echo it to stdout, which the command substitution captures), which is *double-quoted*, so that its output is treated as a *single* word by the shell, so that `input=num1 num2 ...` forms a *single* option-argument.
- `pig` expects *comma-separated* values in this case, whereas brace expansion passed to `echo` results in *space-separated* values, hence the need to translate spaces to commas with `tr ' ' ','`.